# Create a sequence of dates in one data frame based on a second data frame by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data frames that share a grouping ID. I would like to create a sequence of dates in one, based on the conditions set by the other one. MRE as follows:

```
jdates <- structure(list(Group.1 = c(8, 9), x = structure(c(16674, 16661), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Group.1", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

jtrying <- structure(list(id = c(8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9), values1 = 1:6, values2 = 7:12), .Names = c("id", "values1", "values2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

In this example, I would like to create a column of dates in `jtrying` starting from the next date in `jdates` (per group - `Group.1` in `jdates` and `id` in `jtrying`).

With data.table, none of these (terrible) approaches worked:

```
jtrying[ , date := seq(jdates$x + 1, length.out=3, by = 1), by = jdates$Group.1]

jtrying[ , date := seq(jdates$x + 1, length.out=3, by = 1), by = id]

jtrying[ , date := lapply(.SD,(seq(jdates$x + 1, length.out=3, by = 1))), by = id]

jtrying[ , date := lapply(.SD,function(x) seq(jdates$x + 1, length.out=3, by = 1)), by = id]
```

I have been trying data.table approaches, as they are thought to be faster (and the real data is quite big), but in reality, anything (within reason) could do.

My expected result is a data.frame that looks like this:

```
 jtrying
   id values1 values2       date
1:  8       1       7 2015-08-28
2:  8       2       8 2015-08-29
3:  8       3       9 2015-08-30
4:  9       4      10 2015-08-15
5:  9       5      11 2015-08-16
6:  9       6      12 2015-08-17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do

```
jtrying[jdates, 
  date := seq(from=x+1, by=1, length.out=.N)
, on=c(id="Group.1"), by=.EACHI]
```

This syntax `X[Y, newcol := ..., on=c(Xcol=Ycol), by=.EACHI]` works as follows:

- `X` is merged with `Y` on the columns identified in `on`.
- `X` builds its `newcol` separately for each value of the merge columns (i.e., `by=.EACHI`).